# arcserve brightstor 11 next tape email

Tags: tape, backup

Is there anyway of getting brightstor 11 to email out to a group of users when a new tape is required for a backup job (ie when the backup on a particular day spans over multiple tapes). At the moment we have to physically visit the server or rdp to it and check to see if the screen pop has come up.

Answer (score 0):

CA ARCserve r11 is no longer a supported version of ARCserve Backup. CA currently has version r15 out and are almost at version r16.
Reporting and alearts have been greatly enhanced in the latest version with a Dashboard feature that has 38 reports and email alearts.
For version r11, it might be useful to check the guide for alearts. Let me know if you need help finding it.